# App rolling back transactions and I don't know why

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am curious as to why my Rails app is rolling back transactions to DB without it being asked to.

Puma log:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-05 00:32:32 -0500
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1AlwhyE0VY87oSyCyjmrzgxinJ7+t1TfoYYEDXvfl0pGd4DKE842KXHroFWgtXeusOgt+ZApHmB+e40qliTPjQ==", "post"=>{"title"=>"test", "category_id"=>"4", "body"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
User Load (0.3ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ? [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7
(0.2ms) begin transaction
↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:14
Category Load (0.2ms) SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT ? [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:14
(0.1ms) rollback transaction
↳ app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:14
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save(post_params)
      @post.author = current_user.username
      flash[:success] = "Post created."
      redirect_to post_path(@post.id)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Post not created. Redirecting to main page....."
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title, "Title of Post" %>
<%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.label :body, "Post Text" %>
<%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control" %>
<%= f.submit "Create Post", class: "btn btn-info"%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: We need to see the model and its fields.

Comment: To get a descriptive error message replace `save` with `save!`.

Comment: It is because you're trying to create an invalid post

Comment: in your `else` branch, log `@post.errors.full_messages` to see why your post is prevented from being saved in DB

Comment: Does your category id 4 exist? If not, it will show the rollback transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to have validation of the presence of the `author` field. Since it's set incorrectly in the `create` method, you have the transaction rolled back:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save(post_params)
      @post.author = current_user.username
      flash[:success] = "Post created."
      redirect_to post_path(@post.id)

  ...
end
```

In order to have `author` assigned and saved in the db, you need to assign the `author` *before* the saving:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.author = current_user.username

    if @post.save(post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Post created."
      redirect_to post_path(@post.id)

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Rails you have, and if you are using [Strong Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), you must whitelist your parameters in the controller.

Example from docs:

```
private
  # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters
  # is just a good pattern since you'll be able to reuse the same
  # permit list between create and update. Also, you can specialize
  # this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
  end
```